# How to get removed file from svn repository

Tags: file, svn, restore

I have svn repo and I've removed a file somewhere in the past, how can I fetch that file from svn history? Let say I have right now rev 2000 and the file was removed in 1950.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svnbook has a [topic](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect) about how to handle this.

It basically boils down to:

- If the file deletion was the only thing in the commit, you can use `svn merge -c -revnum` to reinstate the file.
- If there were other changes in the commit, you can copy the file from the version before it was deleted -- `svn copy file@revnum file`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to 'get' the file, you can do:

```
svn cat -r 1950 file > file
```

but as has been pointed out, this won't retrieve any of the file history, and will be seen by SVN as a completely new file.

Comment: This doesn't maintain any of the previous history of the file.

Comment: @jamessan the op did say "fetch", which does not necessarily imply needing it back in source control.

Comment: Sure.  Just pointing out a caveat of this approach, in case it is for restoring into source control.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, run `svn log -v` and see if you can find the revision that removed the file.
2. Once you locate where the file was deleted, you can use `svn merge` or `svn cp` to get the file back.

Let's say you need to restore `foo.txt` in `trunk/proj/mydir`:

```
$ svn log -v $REPO/trunk/proj/mydir | less
```

Then you can use `/D .*foo.txt` to search the less output for the file. You find that the file was deleted in revision 1235:

If that was the only thing revision 1235 did, or you decide you want to undo the rest of the stuff in that revision, you can use `svn merge -c`:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates $REPO/trunk/proj/mydir  # No need to checkout sub directories too
$ cd mydir
$ svn merge -c -1235 .                              # Undoes the delete
$ svn commit -m "Restored file 'foo.txt' deleted in revision 1235"
```

Sometimes you simply want to restore the file, and not all the other changes in that revision. In that case, use the `svn cp` command. You could do this without doing a checkout if you prefer:

```
$ svn cp -r1234 -m"Restored $foo.txt removed in rev 1235" \
       $REPO/trunk/proj/mydir/foo.txt@1234 $REPO/trunk/myproj
```

Or you can do it though a checkout:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates $REPO/trunk/proj/mydir  # No need to checkout sub directories too
$ cd mydir
$ svn cp -r1234 foo.txt@1234  .                     # Undoes the delete
$ svn commit -m "Restored file 'foo.txt' deleted in revision 1235"
```

Note that I am using revision 1234 and not 1235 because the file was deleted in revision 1235 and doesn't exist in that revision. I use `-r` to specify that I want revision `1234` of `foo.txt` and I specify `@1234` on the end of the URL to specify that the file exists in revision `1234`of the repository directory layout.

Comment: When I run first command I've got error that Object was not found, it try to search it on a disk.

Comment: The `$REPO` is the URL of your Subversion repository. Not knowing what it is, I just put `$REPO`. If you're repository is on `http://foo.com/svn`, the command would be `svn ls http://foo.com/svn/trunk/proj/mydir` assuming `trunk/proj/mydir` is the directory where the missing file is located.